# Opening Native App. from Safari

Tags: iphone, html, web-applications, safari, hyperlink

I know iPhone apps. operate like sandboxes. Meaning that they don't have access to other apps' files. And I have also managed to open a website in Safari from a Native App() using:

```
 openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: Website_Address]
```

There are four Native apps that I have seen being opened from safari.

1. App Store app
2. Maps app
3. Email app
4. Phone app

Is there a method of opening my own app from an iphone website in Safari(maybe some html/xml/php etc code)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by binding your application to a custom URI scheme and then creating a link with your custom URI scheme which, when selected, will open your app.

To register the custom URI scheme you'll need to modify the info.plist file and assign your custom value to the `URL Identifier` object.

You can review the [iPhone OS Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ApplicationEnvironment/ApplicationEnvironment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW50) Apple developer documentation for further details or [this article](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ApplicationEnvironment/ApplicationEnvironment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW50) which details the step-by-step process in-depth.

Or you can check out the [official documentation from Apple](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html).

Comment: Thanks chrissr. I'm checking it out.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, we would like you to include the essential parts of the linked article in your answer, and provide the [link for reference](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259). Failing to do that leaves the answer at risk from link rot...which in this case has happened with the second link. Thanks.

Comment: @chrissr app is not open from safari by clicking the schema link text

Comment: the link of `this article` is invalid

Comment: The recommended way to do this now is with [Universal Links](https://developer.apple.com/ios/universal-links/).

Comment: Helpful link 1 => https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html

Comment: Helpful link 2 => https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/defining-a-custom-url-scheme-for-your-app?language=objc