# How do I register my app to use the openUrl scheme?

Tags: iphone, ios, openurl

How can I register my iPhone app to open when I use openUrl in another app or in a website (in Safari)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Opening Native App. from Safari](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294286/opening-native-app-from-safari)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add url type and url scheme key in your info.plist file. read this post for detail - http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html

Answer (score 1):

In your app's "info.plist" add a "URL Type".
Add a single item with your app's identifier as "URL Identifier".
Under this, add a single "URL Scheme" with the name of the handler you want.

For example add "myapp" to handle an a URL like "myapp://test/test/test"

Then handle the "handleOpenUrl" call in your app's delegate.

Comment: Do you mean `myapp://`, not `myapp:://`?