# Can you open safari in an iphone app and navigate between local html files?

Tags: iphone, safari

Imagine a website consisting of many html files with hyperlinks between them.
In addition, the html contains jquery and images.

I need an app that installs all these files as a bundle in a users iphone.
When the app starts, it checks the users credentials, launches Safari and then the user navigates between pages via hyperlinks as they would through a website.

I have heard it is possible to [launch Safari from an app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294286/opening-native-app-from-safari).
But can it be directed to a local html file and then can the user navigate between locally installed files via hyperlinks?

I have a feeling it is not possible to navigate between locally installed files but am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

UIWebView allows the developer to target local files. You may need to convert the anchor tags to target the appropriate path and protocol.

Comment: Yes, so long as you set the Base URL property of the UIWebView correctly, Petras.