# PHP Exporting to Excel, on iPad

Tags: php, ios5

I have a script to output a mysql result to excel, which is working just fine in all browsers.
However, I need the script to also work on iPad, opening the excel in Safari. At this moment, the script just "hangs" on the iPad, it keeps loading. Is this a headers problem?
The code headers at this moment:

```
header( 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary' );
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
//header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="' . $_POST['Client_FirstName'] . ' ' .     $_POST['Client_LastName'] . ' ' . $_POST['month'] . '-' . $_POST['year'] . '.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
```

Comment: As far as I know Safari on IOS can not handle file downloads.

Comment: And opening it in a new window?

Comment: Neither, Right now I don't think there's a solution without using a native app.

Comment: Maybe that could help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294286/opening-native-app-from-safari

Comment: Thanks Michi, but that only works if you get to install an app on the iPhone, right? What I am looking for is like when, on my iPad, I open Dropbox in Safari, I get the interface, in Safari, and when I click on an excel file, it opens in a new tab in Safari, also giving me the option to "open with" other apps (dropbox,...)

Comment: The idea behind the link I posted is to have special links to open the Excel file in an native app... there are several ones that can handle XLS. Maybe you could provide more links and let the user choose depending on the apps he has installed.

Comment: I don't know if that could work.. but maybe you could open the Excel file using Google Docs... haven't tried that one though.

Comment: Apparently it was the application/vnd.ms-excel header that caused the problem. Setting it to octet-stream solved the issue, but then caused problems in IE8. So I used this code to totally solve the problem:`if(stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'ipad') OR stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'iphone') OR stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'ipod'))
{
 header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
}else{
 header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
}`

Comment: You mean IOS Safari does open the Excel file?

Comment: Yes it does now. Great isn't it :-)

Comment: It's great and something I never expected. You could answer your own question so others can find the solution.

Comment: Thanks Michi, I thought I had already answered it by posting it to the comments :-) I'm new here, so still learning :-) Added it as an answer now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently it was the application/vnd.ms-excel header that caused the problem. 
Setting it to octet-stream solved the issue, but then caused problems in IE8. 
So I used this code to totally solve the problem:

```
if(stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'ipad') OR stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],     'iphone') OR stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'ipod')) 
{ 
  header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream"); 
}else{ 
  header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel'); 
}
```