# Export HTML content to Excel in iPad/iPhone

Tags: c#, excel, ipad, export

```
byte[] l_ObjBuffer;
            StringBuilder l_StrBldr = new StringBuilder();
            string l_StrFileName = p_ObjFormCollection[1];

            l_StrBldr.Append(Convert.ToString(p_ObjFormCollection[0]));
            l_ObjBuffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(l_StrBldr.ToString());
            l_StrBldr.Clear();

            HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + l_StrFileName + ".xls");

            return new FileContentResult(l_ObjBuffer, "application/vnd.ms-excel");
```

I am using the above code to export the html rendered to excel file(p_ObjFormCollection[0] is the html content).
All works fine until i try it on iPad/iPhone.
How can i make it compatible on iPad/iPhone???

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11449989/php-exporting-to-excel-on-ipad

Comment: How about generating a CSV file instead? It would be more universal.

Comment: I tried generating a csv but it displays the html code in the file.