# Opening my iphone app from iphone safari using php webpage

Tags: php, iphone, openurl

I am a iPhone developer. I know that we can open iphone app from other apps using CustomURL Scheme and calling that from `openURL:` method.

What I am looking for I want to open my app which has some customURLScheme registered in plist file from a php web pages. I have a very little knowledge on PHP. I know that I can check that the client browser from where we got request is iphone safari or not.

now I have following logic to follow:

```
if(Client == iPhoneSafari) {
    //Open My App URL
}
```

For opening app from iphone to iphone we use following code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:myURL];
```

I have checked [This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294286/opening-native-app-from-safari) and I want to make sure that the same code of iphone will work for web page opened in iphone safari or not??

If no than I want to know what code we need to write for samething to do in webpage for opening app.

I know this is very silly to ask for code here.. but I don't know about PHP and I am not aware with syntax.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Check out my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6964515/877465).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Presuming you have already setup the custom URL scheme in your plist file](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html), you can do something like this in PHP:

```
<?php

function isIphone($user_agent=NULL) {
    if(!isset($user_agent)) {
        $user_agent = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] : '';
    }
    return (strpos($user_agent, 'iPhone') !== FALSE);
}

if(isIphone()) {
    //header('Location: myapp://
    //exit();
    ?><a href="myapp://">Tap this to launch application</a><?php
} else {
?><h1>Visit this page in iOS</h1><?php
}

// THE REST OF YOUR CODE HERE

?>
```

You check which browser it is using the UserAgent and then show a hyperlink leading to your custom URL scheme.

You can also use php-mobile-detect: http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/

This has a very convenient function for detecting iPad, iPhone and iPod browsers all in one. The above example works only for iPhone.