# access/open an app from an external browser link

Tags: javascript, ios, wechat

asking if it's possible to open an installed App on iOS, through an external link/web address on a browser?

for instance, a web page with a link on safari browser, then after clicking access for example twitter, and open a specific page. 
in my case would be wechat and then open the built-in browser.  wonder if its possible doing it with javascript or something else.

thanks in advance for your help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Opening Native App. from Safari](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294286/opening-native-app-from-safari)

Comment: Yes its absolutely possible just all you need to find the `URL Scheme` for the app that will launch the app, and the normal `a href` tag would look like `<a href="yourapp://parameter">Your App</a>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can find more info about this here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html with using meta tag in head of html file `<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=myAppStoreID, affiliate-data=myAffiliateData, app-argument=myURL">` and `app-argument` you can do this not in exact way as you are asking, but in Apple's way through their smart app banner. Quotation from Apple:

> app-argument: (Optional.) A URL that provides context to your native
>   app. If you include this, and the user has your app installed, she can
>   jump from your website to the corresponding position in your iOS app.

If this is not the solution, please give more details what you want to do.