# How to open other app installed on IOS from HTML run in Safari

Tags: html, ios, safari

Is there a way to open any app installed on Iphone/Ipad? is there a way to open that app from HTML run in Safari.
Please help me. Thank you very much!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Opening Native App. from Safari](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294286/opening-native-app-from-safari)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but only if you know the apps URL scheme.

Like for example, Facebook App registers the app URL `fb://` so if you create `a herf` you can open the Facebook app:

`<a href="fb://">Launch Facebook app</a>`

Comment: Thank You! , But how to get URL Scheme of App Installed on IOS

Comment: You have two options. 1. Ask the developers. 2. Open the app and find the `info.plist`, in this XML file you look for the key `CFBundleURLTypes` and it subkey `CFBundleURLSchemes` which holds the list of URLs that are associated with the app.

Comment: You can also find a list here: http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes and here: http://handleopenurl.com

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, If you know the URL scheme of that app.

For eg. URL scheme of whatsapp is whatsapp:// so you can open whatsapp from safari by typing whatsapp:// in your browser.

You can also set URL scheme to your app so that any one can open your app from browser by entering URL.

[Check this great tutorial If you want to create a custom URL scheme for your app.](http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html)