# How to open a mobile app (Android or iOS) from a web app using Javascript/PHP

Tags: javascript, php, android, ios, progressive-web-apps

I would like to create a button on my PWA (which could run on an Android or an iOS device) which opens another particular application installed on a device (in this case, the app "VerificaC19", which is needed to verify a Green Pass certification.

Is there any Javascript/PHP code I could use to create a button in the PWA running on the browser which automatically opens the application?

Comment: Opening an app from a mobile website is only possible if the app has registered its domain with the OS. Like for instance if you install instagram, all URLs starting with https://instagram.com will open inside the app if the user has confirmed that to happen. So unless that app has a registered domain, it's not possible. The only thing you can do is send the user to the play store / app store URL for the app; this will usually open the store's page for the app. From there the user can tap on "install" or "open", depending on whether they've already installed it or not.

Comment: Also, PHP can do absolutely nothing here since it runs on your server, not on the device. The only way to actually open the app is to wrap your PWA in an app and use a WebView to display it. This requires publishing your own app to the stores though, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28232467/2361500) for iOS.

You need to know the URL scheme of the app. Specific to iOS and Android there can be different URL Schemes registered with the target app.