# Open iOS app from Safari after downloaded

Tags: ios, swift, safari, appdelegate, nsuseractivity

How do you configure your app to open from safari after it has already been downloaded? In the screenshot below when clicking "Open" it opens the app in the App Store, even after the app is downloaded.

I've implemented `continue userActivity` in the `appDelegate` class:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
        
        if let url = userActivity.webpageURL {
            self.continueWithLink(url: url)
        }
        
        return true
    }
```

What else do I need to do to make it function properly?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Opening Native App. from Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294286/opening-native-app-from-safari)

Comment: Unfortunately it does not, the links provided in that answer pointed to the UIKit documentation